# Does importing a component at run-time in react affects performance of the application?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

If I import a component inside render/componentWillMount, does this affect performance?

for e.g.

```
render() {
    var Comp = require('./App1').default
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 , backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
        <Comp />
      </View>
    )
}
```

The reason I do this is to dynamically replace a page based on JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

`render()` can be called by React many times, and it isn’t destructive. React will compare what you return from `render()`, and use that to choose what to mount and what to unmount.

If you move the alert to `componentDidMount`, you will see what really gets mounted.

Comment: Correct, render will be called multiple times but what if I move the import to componentWillMount?. Will that affects performance since I'm importing on run-time?